# How to use PDF open parameter (e.g. fitH) in Chrome/ FireFox browser?

Tags: css, object, pdf, iframe, browser

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

There are a set of open parameter specify how the viewer should open the pdf . However, with the Chrome and firefox browser's default viewer , it does not work

```
<object id = 'zoomPage' type='application/pdf' data= '1.pdf#view=fit'><p>The PDF can not display</p></object>
```

I have tried the fit which I would like the pdf fill the object. If there is no parameter support , are there any workaround ? I tried a lot of approach but none of them work. For example, I also tried using iframe instead of object. However, the content does not resize. Thanks

```
<iframe src="1.pdf" width=1300 height=3300></iframe>
```

Comment: The document you refer to is part of the Adobe® Acrobat® SDK; it, therefore, as such only applies to situations where a Adobe Acrobat / Reader plugin is used to display the PDF, while other PDF viewers might or might not support that information. You might search the feature request pages for those browsers/pdf viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching a solution for a problem very similar to yours, I found an interesting thread on forum.asp.net. http://forums.asp.net/t/1877403.aspx?Issue+with+embedded+pdf+object+in+chrome+browsers

At the end of the page, there is a workaround by a user working smoothly in Chrome. That seems to solve the problem.

Here it is an example:

```
<iframe src="/Downloads/MyPdfDocument.pdf#view=fitH" width="700"  height="880"></iframe>
```

For users fighting with http://pdfobject.com/ -> "pdfobject.js" like me, you can change few lines of code on both minified and develop version of pdfobject.

Find:

```
c.innerHTML='<object    data="'+a+'" type="application/pdf" width="'+i+'" height="'+z+'"></object>';return c.getElementsByTagName("object")[0];
```

and change with this line of code:

```
c.innerHTML='<iframe src="'+a+'" width="'+i+'" height="'+z+'"></iframe>';return c.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old, but nowadays you can put `#view=fit` on the end of an iframe's src URL to make sure the PDF opens a page to fit within the iframe.