# How do I set view/zoom level of an embed PDF?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I am trying to set the view of an embed PDF. I want it so that when the user clicks and opens the PDF in their browser, the view mode is already set to page width instead of the default automatic zoom.

I have looked at this pdf: http://www.heinelt.info/pdf/PDFOpenParameters.pdf for help.

Adding

```
#view=FitH
```

At the end of the url is what the pdf says to do, but that doesnt work, although things like page jumping ( #page=3 ) do.

Here is how I have my pdf linked

```
<a href="javascript:loadPDF('http://www.pdfpdf.com/samples/Sample3.PDF#view=FitH');"
```

The " javascript:loadPDF " before the link is for embedding the PDF, so that the pdf opens inside the same page. (So the PDF doesnt navigate away from the page or open in a new pdf.)

Help? Am I using the #view=FitH wrong?

Comment: you can refer this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1877403.aspx?Issue+with+embedded+pdf+object+in+chrome+browsers  also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18462054/how-to-use-pdf-open-parameter-e-g-fith-in-chrome-firefox-browser

Comment: I should have mentioned that my object tag would be js generated, as the container that holds the pdf will change as users click on other pdf's.